# Not able to use gimp-fourier plugin on ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: plugins, gimp

I tried to install this fft plugin for GIMP:

https://www.lprp.fr/gimp_plugin_en/

Following:

```
tar xvzf fourier-0.4.*.tar.gz
cd fourier-0.4.*
make clean
make
make install
```

After that, I added the plug-in folder (that was created by the script to copy the compiled plugin i.e `/home/<user>/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/` ) in the plugin folder settings of GIMP.

The fft plugin still doesn't load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem even before posting this question. It seemed like a simple permission issue for GIMP to access that folder. So I just copied the compiled plugin to one of its default plugin folders:

```
/home/<user>/snap/gimp/227/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins
```

Sorry if it's common knowledge. Just posted it so that it might help someone with a similar problem.

Comment: It certainly will, thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge!